# Nested MySQL-Selection

Tags: mysql

A have a table with rows which consists invoice data and person data to which these belong.

Something like

```
name, birthday, sex, invoice_date, invoice_amount
```

First I want to get all datasets for every unique person. So I do a select like this

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE invoice_amount < 10 GROUP BY name, birthday
```

With this I filter all duplicate entries for the same persons.

Now I want to know how many of these persons are female - not all rows, but the grouped result. I mean I want to make a select from the results (I don't think of `WHERE invoice_amount <10 AND sex = 1`). How do I do that?

So how do I do a nested selection for that example case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a subquery:

```
SELECT sex, count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM data WHERE invoice_amount < 10 GROUP BY name, birthday
) s
GROUP BY sex
```

but please notice that is not considered good practice to SELECT all fields, and group by fewer fields without using aggregated functions. I would better write your query this way:

```
SELECT sex, COUNT(DISTINCT name, birthday)
FROM data
WHERE invoice_amount < 10
GROUP BY sex
```

**Update**

The table is not normalized so it can happen that the same person (same name and same birthday) has different sex information on different rows.

You have two options here. You can just ignore the problem, a few mistakes in a big dataset won't (probably) make much difference, so you can use the query with a subquery.

If you `SELECT *` but only use `GROUP BY name, birthday`, you will get just one row for each person with one value for sex (if there are multiple values, the one you will get is unpredictable, but it can be fine on a huge dataset).

But if you want to identify which records are wrong you can use this:

```
SELECT name, birthday
FROM data
GROUP BY name, birthday
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sex)>1
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I see, that my huge database has some little mistakes: there are multiple invoice-data rows but some of them have wrong sex-information. I.e. five rows for Mr. Smith, but in one row he is set as female. So how can I find those datasets?